# Eight distinct integer values between $1$ and $8$ satisfy six simple conditions ($D+E=F$, etc). Find which value is which.

Tags: linear-algebra, puzzle, cryptarithm

> I have 8 variables; $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$, $G$, and $H$.
>
> What are they all equal to?
>
> Rules:
>
> 1. All the variables are equal to integer values between one and eight.
> 2. None of the variables are equal to each other.
> 3. $D + E = F$
> 4. $B + C = D$
> 5. $B + H = A$
> 6. $C + G = F$
> 7. $E + G = H$
> 8. $B + E = G$

I know that $1$ and $2$ both must be either $B$, $C$, or $E$ since there is no $0$ so $1$ must be a letter that does not have an equation answer. For $2$ I know that there is no equation that is the a variable plus itself.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: This doesn't seem related to random variables, but more along the lines of linear algebra.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can't think of how to start...

Comment: I know b c or f have to be 1

Comment: @RedGuy11: You should [edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3358449/edit) to include what you know (and how you know it!). Comments are easily overlooked, so your question could accumulate down-votes and close-votes for not demonstrating any effort on your part. (The community is here to *help* you, and it likes some assurance that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. Plus, including your own thoughts saves people from wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know.)

Comment: "*I know B C or F have to be 1*"  But $D+E=F$.  Remembering that $D\geq 1$ and $E\geq 1$ and $D\neq E$ and that these are integers implies that $F\geq 3$.  You probably meant "B, C, or E" instead.

Comment: Did you try to use Gaussian elimination?

Comment: This is a **puzzle**. You are not supposed to start working according to some standard textbook method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in the post ${B,C,E}$ contains the numbers $1$ and $2$. Similarly ${A,F}$ contains 8.

The equations give $A=2(B+E),H=B+2E,G=B+E$. $A$ must therefore be either $6$ or $8$.

If $A=6$, then $B=1,E=2, F=8,G=3,H=5$ or $B=2,E=1,G=3,F=8,H=4$.

If $A=8$, then $B=1,C=2,E=3,G=4,H=7$ or $B=3,C=2,E=1,G=4,H=5$.

> The actual solution is $A=6,B=2,C=5,D=7,E=1,F=8,G=3,H=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

Since $8$ cannot occur on the left hand side of an equation, we know that either $A=8$ or $F=8$.

From equations $1$ and $2$ we know that $B+C+E=F$. So $F=6,7$ or $8$.

From equations $5,7,8$ we know that $A=B+H = B+E+G=2G$. Since $G \ge 3$ we have either $G=3, A=6$ or $G=4, A=8$.

Suppose $G=3$. Then $A=6$ and so $F=8$. From equation $8$ we know that $B$ and $E$ are $1$ and $2$ (either way round), so $C=5$ (because $B+C+E=F=8$). Since $E+G=H$ we know that $E$ cannot be $2$ (otherwise $H=C=5$) so $E=1$ and $B=2$.

This should be enough for you to find one solution.

You should also consider the case "Suppose $G=4$ ..." to see if there are any other solutions.

Comment: @RedGuy11 Why ? There is nothing in our answering guidelines about posting hints as comments, and my hints were too long to put into a comment. You said "I can't think of how to start" so I suggested an approach.